# Mean Stack CRUD with JWT session token

Tags: node.js, angular, crud, mean, express-jwt

I'm trying to setup a mean stack CRUD operation that would work with JWT token, which means the CRUD will use the jwt token to get the current user id and perform its operations on that id. Users can create data that would be connected to their user id. I just need to get the create operation to work, i'll figure the rest out. The codes below are where i'm getting the errors from, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

`addbio.page.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.fetchBio(this.id);
      this.addBio = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: [''],
        details: [''],
        dob: ['']
      })
  }

  fetchBio(id) {
    this.bioCrudService.getBio(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.addBio.patchValue({
        title: data['title'],
        details: data['details'],
        dob: data['dob']
      });
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.addBio.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.bioCrudService.createBio(this.addBio.value)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.addBio.reset();
            this.showAnimation = 'rotateanimationinfinite'

            setTimeout(() => {
              this.showAnimation = 'rotateanimation'
              this.showSuccess();
            }, 3000);
          })
        });
    }
  }
```

`boi-crud.service.ts`

```
export class BioCrudService {

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `bearer ${this.token.getToken()}`
       })
  };

  constructor(...) { }

  createBio(bio: Bio): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Bio>('http://localhost:5000/api/create-bio/', bio, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<Bio>('Error occured'))
      );
  }

  getBio(id): Observable<Bio[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Bio[]>('http://localhost:5000/api/fetch-bio/' + id)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log(`Bio fetched: ${id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Bio[]>(`Get bio id=${id}`))
      );
  }

}
```

Below are the errors i'm getting.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

```
Get bio id=USER_ID_HERE failed: Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/fetch-bio/USER_ID_HERE: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 0):

First : I would add the Bearer with an angular interceptor, just a precaution for reusability of course.

Second : why would you do the zone.run call ?

Third : you have an HTTP 500 error from your server ? It's not related to your angular code right ? Did you try to solve that before ? And if ever it doesn't work, why don't you mock the server to get rid of this aspect for a while.

And last : you show an error, but you should have the precise line in your code where it happens, that could help a lot.

Cheers